# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY change duplicated value and insert

Tags: mysql

My table consist of several columns, the first of which is PK AI `ID` and another one is unique `TIME`. There is a chance that two inserts can have the same `TIME` value. I would want to insert both of them and change the `TIME` value in the second INSERT by incrementing it, calling NOW(), or in any other possible way. Is it possible in one MySQL query?

Comment: Why not remove the `unique` constraint on `time`? It seems you want to allow duplicates.

Comment: You can do this only using a trigger

Comment: @ypercube, the `TIME` is a time the query starts running at so even if it is in ms there is a chance two instances could run it at once. I would want to use this column in another query and it would be nice to keep it unique, but it seems its impossible doing it this way.

Comment: If you can use the `(time,id)` combination (which is unique anyway) in your other queries, I'd say remove the unique constraint on time.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in a single query because `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will only update the existing row.  It will not affect a newly inserted row.

One possible course of action would be to do the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query and check the affected rows to determine whether there was an insert or an update.  If there was an update, just do another insert to replace the time again.  This will not work if there is a tie-in between `time` and the `ID` (vs. just needing a record of times).

Comment: I will lost data stored in another columns of this row if i update it.